# What is the best/most efficient way to search for an object in an array inside another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am building a simple application that stores places I've visited. I have a local express server using a db.json file as my database. I am making 2 requests and experiencing a problem.

What I'm trying to do is iterate over both arrays so that when the app loads, countries I've been too are already preselected. this seems like a super expensive call to make and has quite slow performance already

Also it's not actually doing what I want until I trigger a second re-render of the DOM and then it updates.

e.g. if I pre-select Croatia and France in the database and then load the app, none are selected. but if I then select Korea (e.g.) then in the visited list, suddenly all 3 are visible

what would be a better way to compare the arrays? considering the object keys are not necessarily the same

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').then((data) => {
  const updatedCountries = data.data.map((country) => {
    return {...country, visited: false, cities: [], showCities: false}
  })
  axios.get('http://localhost:3007/countries').then((countries) => {
    const visitedCountries = countries.data
    for (var i = 0; i < visitedCountries.length; i++){
      for (var k = 0; k < updatedCountries.length; k++){
        if(visitedCountries[i].name === updatedCountries[k].name){
          updatedCountries[k].visited = true
        }
      }
    }
  })
  this.setState({countries: updatedCountries})
})
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need update state in second request success callback function

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').then((data) => {
  const updatedCountries = data.data.map((country) => {
    return {...country, visited: false, cities: [], showCities: false}
  })
  axios.get('http://localhost:3007/countries').then((countries) => {
    const visitedCountries = countries.data
    for (var i = 0; i < visitedCountries.length; i++){
      for (var k = 0; k < updatedCountries.length; k++){
        if(visitedCountries[i].name === updatedCountries[k].name){
          updatedCountries[k].visited = true
        }
      }
    }

    this.setState({countries: updatedCountries})
  })

})
  }
```

For efficient way to search

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3007/countries').then((countries) => {
    let visitedCountriesName = new Set(countries.data.map(country => country.name));
    updatedCountries = updatedCountries.map((country) => {
        if (visitedCountriesName.has(country.name)) country.visited = true
        return country
    });
    this.setState({countries: updatedCountries})
})
```

Comment: oh cool, so it was just a small thing. and in terms of efficiency, is this the best way? (will accept answer when it lets me)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an array to store updatedCountries, you should instead use an object. That way instead of having each element of updatedCountries compare to every element of visitedCountries, you can do a constant lookup. This will change your lookup speed from (n*n) to (n).

The reason why you do not initially see any updates is because you have an async call:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3007/countries')
```

inside of a synchronous function. As a result, you are resetting the state while you are making the get request. Instead you should chain your api calls like

```
axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').then((data) => {
  // edit data
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3007/countries')
}).then((data) => {
  // run function comparing both data
  this.setState({countries: updatedCountries})
})
```